# jquery append with checkbox, if checked, it wont return anything?

Tags: php, jquery, dhtml

I have dynamically generated a list of wine types from the database using AJAx and PHP
here is the function

```
function wineTypeHandler(data){
            var Type = data.Type;
            var countType = data.countType;
            for(var i = 0; i < countType; i++){

                $("#selectType").append(

                $("<input />").attr({
                  type: 'checkbox',
                    name: 'Type',
                    class: 'wineTypeCheck',
                     value: Type[i]
                  }), Type[i] + "<br />"
            );
            }   
        }
```

As you can see I have "appended" the results to some div with id selectType, this whole thing works fine, my only problem is when I want to update another list based on what has been checked from this list, it doesnt respond to anything!. When i try this one and many other ways

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$(':checkbox').click(function(){
alert('started');

    // other code
        return true;

});
```

});

It doesnt alert anything!! Can anybody help me with this problem.

thank you in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`.click()` attaches itself to elements that exist when the DOM is created. Your elements are being dynamically generated, so `.click()` doesn't actually get applied to them.

You should use `.live()` to target dynamically generated elements, as it attaches itself to any element that is created after the DOM is initially loaded. I also suggest using the `change` event instead of a `click`:

```
$(':checkbox').live('change', function(){
  // No need to return true;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because you are assigning the click function once your page has loaded but before your checkboxes have been dynamically created.
Depending on what version of jQuery you are using you can use the [on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/)  (for jQuery version 1.7 or above), [delegate()](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) (for older versions of jquery) or live() (simple but inefficient) functions to register an event to dynamically created elements.

Comment: By JavaScript, I think you mean jQuery ;)

Answer (score 0):

The event is bound only to the existing elements. You need to use [live](http://api.jquery.com/live/)

```
$(':checkbox').live("click", function(){
    alert('started');
});
```

EDIT:

As of jQuery 1.7, the [.live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/) method is deprecated. Use .on() to attach event handlers. Users of older versions of jQuery should use .delegate() in preference to [.live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/).

jQuery 1.4.3+ use [delegate](http://api.jquery.com/delegate)

```
$(#selectType).delegate(':checkbox', "click", function(){
    alert('started');
});
```

jQuery 1.7+ use [on](http://api.jquery.com/on)

```
$(#selectType).on("click", ':checkbox', function(){
    alert('started');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just try this

```
$(':checkbox').live('change', function(){

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to bind the click event after the element has been added to the DOM. This is a popular problem for JavaScript development. I'd recommend creating a function that sets the bind event, and calling it after your append call (as well as on jQuery(document).ready()).

Edit: I see a lot of recommendations for jQuery.live() It's important to note that the live() method of jQuery is deprecated and should not be used.